# Are Virtual Machine images (virtual appliances) recommendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask for instance:

> I want a VirtualBox VM that does a Gopher server.
>   Is there one readily available?
>   *[Plus needed requirements/etc to make the question acceptable]*

Great answers would be maintained VMs, such as the ones from http://www.turnkeylinux.org

Comment: I'll post a more complete *opinion* later - but the correct term for this is a virtual appliance I think, and I'm *slightly* meh on this. Oddly I'd consider *having* a virtual appliance available for a software package a reasonable condition for a question.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you're correct, the term is "appliance" (see the phrasing of the example question in my answer below). And yes, I see this a "reasonable condition" on a software request, obviously – in most cases replacing the OS requirement. Curious for your "meh" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say yes – as basically this is just an additional requirement (supplementing the OS part – as with an appliance, the OS part becomes obsolete). Of course this assumes that your question otherwise sticks to our "quality rules" – if the quote in your question represents your full question, I'd think about voting to close it as "too broad" :)

So let me give a better example of what I'd consider perfectly fine:

> I want a VirtualBox VM / appliance that provides a web server:
>
> - must be light-weight / have minimal resource usage
> - static pages are the only thing to be delivered, so no fancy scripting/CGI stuff
> - document_root must be easily accessible from the host (to copy stuff there)
> - high security, SSL support is a must
> - should work out-of-the-box with minimal configuration needs (if any at all)
> - the VM must be well maintained, especially concerning security fixes
>
> As maintenance is an important requirement here, I'm willing to pay a yearly subscription fee – but that shouldn't exceed USD 50. Free and open-source solutions preferred.

This would fit our "quality rules" (all requirements are mentioned), and it's asking for software. I'd see no reason why such a question should not fit on our site.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd see the availability of Virtual Appliances as a *requirement* - much like you'd ask for say "Properly documented installation notes" for a webapp.

You'd then be able to put various options in one answer for the software, or set up your own. That way you'd focus on a software recommendation (that might be useful even if the appliance is no longer supported, or you decide to build your own) rather than a list of possible appliances.

I'd say the same would be true if you wanted, say vagrant or docket support - its a requirement, not a end goal

Comment: That's how I meant it in my answer as well – thanks and +1 for underlining it explicitly!